# Method not found in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am facing a mysterious problem.When I press submit it shows

> Method App\Http\Controllers\RentController::store_data does not exist.

I am trying to find out but can't. Thanks in advance.

In my route

```php
Route::post('/save_rent', 'RentController@store_data');
```

In my controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Session;
use App\rent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RentController extends Controller
{
    public function store_data(Request $request)
    {
        dd('12');
    }
}
```

In my view

```php
<form 
    class="form form-horizontal"
    action="{{ url('save_rent') }}"
    method="POST"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Comment: What's the relative path to your controller? It should be the same as the namespace.

Comment: Run the command `composer dump-autoload` in the root of the project. See if it works.

Comment: ok, i checked it's already there

Comment: after executing **composer dump-autoload** there is no change

Comment: Does the route appear if you call `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: it's there..........

Comment: Is the `RentController.php` in the `/app/Http/Controllers/` directory?

Comment: yes...............

Comment: can you show your route file ? @mrmithun

Comment: show your web.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a name for that route. Like below

```
Route::post('/save_rent', 'RentController@store_data')->name('rent.store.data');
```

Then call the form action with route name on it

```
action="{{ route('rent.store.data') }}
```

Update:

Another main issue noticed is your extend to `Controller` is not defined.

You should add this on your controller file

`use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

It has be look like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Session;
use App\rent;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RentController extends Controller
{
    public function store_data(Request $request)
    {
        dd('12');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name the route and use the route name in form.

```
Route::post('/save_rent', 'RentController@store_data')->name('rent.store');
```

In your form

```
<form 
 class="form form-horizontal" action="{{ route('rent.store') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

I didn't find any error in your controller.
Hope it works !